# in python is it possible to write a method that will be automatically called after __init__ of subclass

Tags: python, subclass

I am writing a library that are used by others.

For each important functionality, I have a base class. The users are supposed to subclass these, and add their version of important methods.

Now I think I need to add a "setup()" function that will have to run after the **init**() of subclass, but there are already different subclasses of `Problem` there, and I would like not to have people touch those.

I develop on 2.7, too.

Say:

```
class Problem:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        #this and that

    def setup(self,**kwargs):
        #Generic stuff that needs to be done after SpecificProblem.__init__() is called.

class SpecificProblem(Problem):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        Problem.__init__(self,**kwargs)
        #this and that
```

Comment: This can be done with a metaclass that automatically decorates `__init__` on class construction. (I don't have a code example right now, I'll provide one later tonight (PST))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

gabe's answer is what you should go with, but this is a problem that is amenable to metaclasses; without further exposition:

```
class SetupClass(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # create the instance as normal.  this will invokoe the class's
        # __init__'s as expected.
        self = super(SetupClass, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)

        # this steps through the MRO in ascending order (so that child
        # classes can be confident their bases are "set up").  A corresponding
        # teardown() method should probably be `reversed(cls.__mro__)`
        for base in cls.__mro__:
            setup = vars(base).get('setup')
            # in the general case, we have to use the descriptor protocol
            # to setup methods/staticmethods/classmethods properly
            if hasattr(setup, '__get__'):
                setup = setup.__get__(self, cls)
            if callable(setup):
                setup()

        return self

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = SetupClass
    def __init__(self):
        print "A.__init__"
    def setup(self):
        print "A.setup"
class B(A):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B.__init__"
        super(B, self).__init__()
```

```
>>> B()
B.__init__
A.__init__
A.setup
```

Answer (score 8):

Rather than having subclasses overwrite `__init__`, you should have them write a method called `make`.  As in:

```
class Problem:
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.make(**kwargs)
        self.setup(**kwargs)

    def setup(self,**kwargs):
        #Generic stuff that needs to be done after SpecificProblem.__init__() is called.

    def make(self,**kwargs):
        # method to be overwritten by subclasses
        pass

class SpecificProblem(Problem):
    def make(self,**kwargs):
        #this and that
```

There are different approaches to this problem. a metaclass approach would make sense if you want people who write SpecificProblem to be in charge of everything that gets done and when it gets done. However, if you want to appropriately "separate concerns", then my way allows you to do that.

Comment: Nice, but I would probably call the method to be overwritten something less easily confused with `__init__` itself.

Comment: I am inclined to agree (see my change), although it comes down to the same basic issue, which is that whoever writes `SpecificProblem` needs to know that they need to overwrite not `__init__` but `make`. Ideally, you would somehow prevent overwriting of `__init__`.

Comment: @gabe: I think since you changed your answer to use the name `make` instead of `init`, 3rd line of your example code should have been `self.make(**kwargs)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the `Problem.setup` in the `__init__` of `SpecificProblem`

```
class SpecificProblem(Problem):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        Problem.__init__(self,**kwargs)
        #this and that
        Problem.setup(self, **kwargs)
```

You should *really* use new-style classes in python, as they are the default in python 3.x.

```
class Problem(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        pass
    def setup(self, **kwargs):
        pass

class SpecificProblem(Problem):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(SpecificProblem, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        # In python three, super().__init__(**kwargs) works.
        super(SpecificProblem, self).setup(**kwargs)
```